# Can you have two .ascx controls talk to each other via javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

I have control1 which makes an ajax call and depending on what is returned I may need to call a javascript function on control2.

Both live within the same page.

Is there a way to do this?

I'm using C#

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. JavaScript lives on the client end and doesn't really care how it gets composited into the final page from the server side.

However, are you sure that this is a good architecture? Shouldn't your ASCX user controls be self contained?

Comment: Well, it may not be the best architecture but we're dealing with a request to an already existing production application. I've added a javascript function in control1 and tried to call it fro control2, but didn't work. I'm trying to figure out how to make it happen.

Comment: Perhaps instead of asking if it's possible, you should ask for help with your problem.